# interaction between package amsbooka and memo-l class used for Memoirs of the AMS

Tags: table-of-contents, amsbook

I'm trying to compile a book using the style file memo-l used for Memoirs of the AMS. I also need to specify different authors for different chapters of the book, so I'm trying to use the amsbooka package.

However, I end up with a table of contents written very small and an abstract, also written in small characters and justified on the right.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem? It might have to do with the copyright command, since it appears right before the problem.

Anyway, here is some minimal example:

```
\documentclass{memo-l}

\usepackage{amsbooka} %to be able to specify authors by chapter 

\begin{document}

\title{My great book}

\author{My Own Self}
\address{My Home}

\date{\today}
\begin{abstract}
Why is my abstract written so small and right justified? Why is the 
table of contents written so small?
\end{abstract}

\frontmatter

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter[My short title]{My long title}

\section*{Introduction}

Blu blu

\section{My main section}

Bli bli

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've added [amsbook] to the tags, since that is what `memo-l.cls` is built on.  I'm not sure that `memo-l` has ever been tested with `amsbooka`; I've notified the relevant person at the AMS to look into this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Barbara.

Comment: Just to clarify, the reason I didn't add the tag "amsbook" is because everything works fine using simply the document class amsbook. It's specifically with the memo-l.cls class that there is a problem (and I can't add that as a new tag, because I do not have enough reputation points).

Comment: The reason I added the tag [amsbook] is because having just the tag [table-of-contents] would likely be noticed by too many visitors for whom AMS publications, in particular the Memoirs, would be irrelevant.  And creating a tag specifically for the Memoirs would be overkill -- it's really too specialized.  I try to compromise on a "reasonable" target.